# jQuery gallery code only works after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, loading, image-gallery, page-refresh

I'm having trouble implementing a gallery/portfolio, just like the ones pictured in the [portfolio templates of Wix](https://www.wix.com/website-template/view/html/1583?originUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.wix.com%2Fwebsite%2Ftemplates%2Fhtml%2Fportfolio-cv%2F1&bookName=&galleryDocIndex=5&category=portfolio-cv). In my HTML I have set up three div columns, in which I add images, and my thought process was to create a script which adds each image (from a list of images) to the column which currently has the smallest height.

I've already used CSS to ensure that the images are full width in the columns and have margins between each other.

The problem I've been having is that the script seems to work but only after I **refresh** the page--otherwise the heights returned are nonsense values like 0px and 20px, where they should be 356.2px, 306.4px, etc, or arbitrary image height values. Since 0px is being returned, the images go into the same column.

Some visuals to better describe what I mean:
[What I get after the first refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MI9l.png)
vs [What I get before the first refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRnTc.png)

I've looked at some questions with similar problems, and many explain that the image might not have been loaded yet. I've tried `$(window).on('load', function...` , `$(img).onload`, `$('#gallery-holder-1').ready`, ... and a bunch of other random stuff but nothing seems to work.

My code looks like the following:

```
/* List of images */
const images = ["img1.png", "img2.png", "img3.png", "img4.png", "img5.png"];

$(document).ready(function() {
  var holder = 0; // to determine which holder to add to
  var height1 = 0; // heights of each gallery-holder
  var height2 = 0;
  var height3 = 0;

  // add all the images to the holders
  for (const image of images) {

    // get height of each holder
    height1 = $('#gallery-holder-1').css("height");
    height2 = $('#gallery-holder-2').css("height");
    height3 = $('#gallery-holder-3').css("height");

    // find smallest height
    if(height3 < height2) {
      if (height3 < height1) { holder = 3; }
      else { holder = 1; }
    }
    else {
      if (height2 < height1) { holder = 2; }
      else { holder = 1; }
    }

    // create image and append
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = image; 
    $(`#gallery-holder-${holder}`).append(img);
  }
});
```

Does anyone know what might be the problem or, alternatively, a better way to implement a portfolio like the kind on Wix?

Comment: Honestly i'm not quite sure whether it could be the problem, but can you try to use `$(#gallery-holder-X').height();` rather Than `).css('height')`? Otherwise I believe it's looking for a css property. Otherwise you could try to wrap the entire code in a `setTimeout(function (){ ...... },10000);` to test if it's Indeed Because images Arent loaded

Comment: Thanks for the help! I've implemented both your suggestions, and `height()` didn't work but it does condense my code a little. With your `setTimeout()` advice, I did some experiments figured out that if I created all the image elements first (with a separate for loop), and appended them after waiting 10 seconds, the function works. So I looked up a way to load all the images first and then append them, and it worked. Thank you!